# Tomcat servlet configure JNDI

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jndi, pool

Good day, respective all!
My environment:
Tomcat 8.5 under windows 64-bit
All needed jars are placed into $CATALINA_HOME/lib

It is my first attempt to write servlet using ConnectionPool.
After "googling"I made an entry inside $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml:

```
  <context docbase="msgsend" path="/msgsend" reloadable="true">
        <context docbase="ssr" path="/ssr" reloadable="true">
  <Resource 
       name="jdbc/OrServlet"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       user="STERN"
       username="STERN"
       password="pwdxxx"
       driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:STERN/pwdxxx@XEPDB1" 
   />
 </context>
```

I included following into WEb-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
      <description>just a test</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/OrServlet</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

When I try to connect to Oracle in traditional way:

```
try {
cn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@XEPDB1", "STERN", "pwdxx");
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

everything works fine.

But when I try to connect through context:

```
 Connection cn = null;
DataSource ds = null;
 try
 {
 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
 Context envCtx = (Context)initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
 ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/OrServlet");
 
 cn = ds.getConnection();
 }
 catch(NamingException n) {}       
 catch(SQLException s) {out.println(ds.getClass().getName()+" exception "+s);
 ;}
```

I get :

```
 **exception java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'**
```

and ds.getClass().getName() in exception handler returns:
**org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource**

which is distinct from javax.sql.DataSource as declared in
 and .

And it seems to me that **ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/OrServlet")**
doesn't wvwn try to look inside Resource section.

What I missed?
Any help will be very appreciated.

Regards,
Andrew.

Comment: Did you try with `driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"`?

Comment: Piotr, yes I did. Suddenly I found a solution - by copying Resource section to **<GlobalNamingResources>** part of server.xml + creating **<ResourceLiink>** element in **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml**, and by creating a **context.xml.default** file wirh contents of my application context to the **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina/localhost** directory. Whiich part of these steps played a positive role, I don't jnow, and even don't want to know :-) because feel myself tired too much with this boring configuration.